# select column in excel based on corresponding columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want a keyboard shortcut to select column based on other column. For example, I don't want to be like this:

[image: look at this image for more detail]

I want it to be like this:

[image: look at this image for more detail]

Comment: What are we looking at and what are you trying to accomplish?  This is like one of those puzzles that asks you to find the different between two pictures that contain a lot of detail to hide the difference.  Based on PeterH's answer, I noticed the difference in range selection in column A.  Please edit the question to be much more explicit about what you're showing us and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I think what you want is to select all cells in column A from A1 to An, where n is the last row in column B that has data.  Assuming no empty cells in column B, you can (1) select B1, (2) enter CTRL + ARROW DOWN (this will take you to the last cell in B with data, which I'm calling Bn) (3) enter Left Arrow (which will move to to An (3) enter CTRL + SHIFT + ARROW UP (this will select the cells you want.)

Answer (score 1):

Record a macro, and do the follow actions.

Select B1, press CTRL + ARROW DOWN, press LEFT, Press CTRL + SHIFT + ARROW UP

assign macro to  keyboard short cut.

Your question is very vague (and likely to be closed), so my answer is also very vague.

But in principal you need to do something like this.